# How can I create a new list with each element a regular expression of each element of another list in python?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I've been playing around with some different syntaxes but nothing seems to work, I've gotten syntax errors "TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment" and a few othes

```
for url in urls:
  for i in range(len(urls)):    
    filename[i] = [re.search(r'/([.]+)(.pdf)') for url[i] in urls]
```

I've also tried:

```
for url in urls:
    filename[i] = [re.search(r'/([.]+)(.pdf)') for url[i] in urls for i in range(len(urls))]
```

And a few other permutations. I've been thinking a list comprehension is the best way to go about doing this, but I'm not sure the syntax I'd need o use to do so. 
Any help, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right track with a list comprehension, but you were making it more complex than it is:

```
[re.search(r'/([.]+)(.pdf)', url) for url in urls]
```

Note that this will be a list of matches, if you want, for example, the groups it finds, ignoring any urls it doesn't match, you could do:

```
[match.groups() for match in (re.search(r'/([.]+)(.pdf)', url) for url in urls) if match]
```

Which uses a nested generator expression to do a check if the match has been made, and extract the groups from it if it has:

```
>>> urls = ["http://wwww.example.com/test.html", "http://www.example.com/test.pdf"]
>>> [match.groups() for match in (re.search(r'/([^/]+)(.pdf)', url) for url in urls) if match]
[('test', '.pdf')]
```

Here I made a slight edit to your regex to make it work for my examples, this is done just for the example.

Of course, you could do whatever you want with the [match objects](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#match-objects) here, instead of just getting `match.groups()`.

Comment: Thanks, that seems like it should work, but the only issue is my resulting list is filled with objects like "_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x1544ba0" And while I've definitely run into this before and been able to convert these to strings, I seem to be at a loss right now- any help? Thanks.

Comment: @rab777hp See my second example.

Comment: @rab777hp That implies that all of the matches were empty. You might want to check your regular expression is right. Your current one matches any number of `"."`s followed by `".pdf"`.

Comment: Yeah I've been messing around and trying to get this stuff to work, but the stuff before the .pdf is random text of both numbers and letters. I though that putting the . in brackets like [.] makes it mean anything even though it's in ()

Comment: @rab777hp Quite the opposite. The `.` means anything *unless* you put it in square brackets or escape with a backslash. See my third example, where I use the regex for anything except a `/`.

Comment: Thanks!!! That fixes EVERYTHING, wow, I was using a reference for regex which legit claimed that

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension, I created a list of urls, and the url regex result is only inserted into the new list if it matches the pattern

```
file_regex = re.compile(r'/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(.pdf)')

filenames = [file_regex.search(url) for url in urls if file_regex.match(url)]

print filenames
```

Comment: This is a little wasteful, as it will have to match the regex twice.

Comment: @Brian: Even with a compiled regular expression, it's still checking for a match, then finding the match again to store it.